# Selectively controlling firing of angular $watch when comparing object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I want to use angular `$watch` to check for changes in an object like this:

```
$scope.$watch( function(scope) { return scope.selectedTopic },
  function(newVal, oldVal){
     if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        $scope.hasChanges = true;
     }
  }, true);
```

The problem is that that the variable `$scope.selectedTopic` is a placeholder for the current Topic in my application. So if the user selects another Topic, the application overwrites `$scope.selectedTopic` entirely with a `factory`:

```
TopicService.get(id).success(function(data){
  $scope.selectedTopic.content = data;
});
```

So I want to effectively block the `$watch` `oldVal` vs `newVal` comparison only when the `factory` is called.

I tried adding a bool variable to switch off the comparison like so:

```
$scope.$watch( function(scope) { 
  if (scope.isLoadingFromFactory) return scope.selectedTopic
  }, function(newVal, oldVal){
     if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        $scope.hasChanges = true;
     }
  }, true);

TopicService.get(id).success(function(data){
  $scope.isLoadingFromFactory = false;
  $scope.selectedTopic.content = data;
  $scope.isLoadingFromFactory = true;
});
```

but that didn't work. Is there a way to turn on/off the $watch inequality test?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you need but you should be able to unregister the watch like so. You would just need a mechanism to add it back at the right time.

```
var unreg = $scope.$watch( function(scope) { 
      return scope.selectedTopic;
     }, 
     function(newVal, oldVal){
         if($scope.isLoadingFromFactory) {
             unreg();
             return;
         }

         if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            $scope.hasChanges = true;
         }
  }, true);
```

or maybe

```
$scope.$watch( function(scope) { return scope.selectedTopic },
   function(newVal, oldVal){
     if (!$scope.isLoadingFromFactory && newVal !== oldVal) {
        $scope.hasChanges = true;
   }
}, true);
```